# Powershell TLS1.2 on remote servers

Tags: powershell

I have been working on a script to enable TLS1.2, and install some packages/modules for all our servers and am having some trouble. Over RDP, I am able to register repositories, and download packages. In this case, I am trying to install the NuGet package which works while signed into the server. Remotely however, I am getting behavior similar to as if the server wasn't running TLS1.2

> WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload «https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
> WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
> WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
> No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'Nuget'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider

The command I am running is below:

> Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock { Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget}

Is the remote request defaulting back to older TLS ciphers somehow? I am stumped.

Comment: Try adding `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` before your call to`Install-PackageProvider`.  Also, ensure your remote user context, execution policy, environment settings, UAC settings, and any proxy configurations are identical to your RDP session.  It may help to temporarily use a persistent session -- created with New-PSSession -- to investigate the issue more in-depth.